# custom single page without wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

Hi i am creating a website where i am trying to create a single page where data coming from different database which is not related to `WordPress Database`.

i created a loop where it show many posts just like `WordPress` but its not coming from `WordPress` post type etc. just doing with simple `mysqli_query`. now for that loop i want to create a single page show i can show full details just like `WordPress` post.

*Example i create this virtual url:-*
http://example-website.com/handbuch-der-mechanischen-verfahrenstechnik/B009CCTW9M

now "`B009CCTW9M`" is the `id` with that i will create `mysqli_query` to show single post.

but when i got to that url `WordPress` show `404 Error` because it does not exist in `WordPress Database`.

i think its need to be done through `mod_rewrite` but i am not expert of it please help me to figure it out.

sorry guys for not clear description may be this will help you

i created a `mysqli_query` to show some data just like WordPress do with "`while (have_posts()) : the_post();`"

but difference is my data is not coming from WordPress database structure. so for that data which i am showing i need to create a single page. so can show its full details like WordPress single page do. for that i have to create some url but i am not sure how i create it so WordPress don't give `404 Error`. on that url i want this id '`B009CCTW9M`' so i can extract it and create `mysqli_query`.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: lol that's the question what should i try to achieve that. but first time i tried this that i register post type ebook and then i though i will open url like this http://example-website.com/ebook/handbuch-der-mechanischen-verfahrenstechnik/B009CCTW9M

and then i will extract id from url and use it for query but i think this is very stupid think because wordpress showing 404 error for that url.

Comment: your q is not very clear, the db/loop has nothing to do with the url or  , you need to show how you have created the url, if it is a wp rewrite, save permalinks or is it a page template/ page etc. If you are trying to hit a specific id on the page, you need a `#B009CCTW9M`  to hit either a named anchor or id on the page

Comment: wordpress ajax call can be used to fetch the details in single page.. URL cannot be rewrited. In th url above WP searches for `andbuch-der-mechanischen-verfahrenstechnik` as a parent page having  `B009CCTW9M` as a child page ...

Comment: instead use wp_ajax call passing the `B009CCTW9M` as id in ajax call and getting the records through you normal query..

Comment: @PrakashRao i think i am not clear about what i am trying to achieve here. 

i created a mysqli_query to show some data just like wordpress do with "while (have_posts()) : the_post();"  but difference is my data is not comming from wordpress database structure. so for that data which i am showing i need to create a single page. so can show its full details like wordpress single page do. for that i have to create some url but i am not sure how i create it. on that url i want this id 'B009CCTW9M' so i can extract is and create mysqli_query

Comment: http://example-website.com/handbuch-der-mechanischen-verfahrenstechnik this link is also not working .. If it work then you can change the URL to http://example-website.com/handbuch-der-mechanischen-verfahrenstechnik/?B009CCTW9M and get the ID by `$_REQUEST[B009CCTW9M]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi sorry for late answer this is my solution which help me hope this will help other guys to.

```
function userpage_rewrite_catch() {
global $wp_query;

if ( array_key_exists( 'ebooks_id', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
            include WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/'. plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__) ) .'/single-ebook.php';
exit;
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'userpage_rewrite_catch' );

function userpage_rewrite() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init','userpage_rewrite');


function ebook_plugin_activate() {
  products_plugin_rules();
  flush_rewrite_rules();
 }

 function ebook_plugin_deactivate() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
 }

 function ebook_plugin_rules() {
  //add_rewrite_rule('ebook/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=ebook&ebook_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
      add_rewrite_rule( 'ebooks/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?ebooks=$matches[1]&ebook_cat=$matches[2]&ebooks_id=$matches[3]', 'top' );
 }

 function ebook_plugin_query_vars($vars) {
   $vars[] = 'ebooks';   
  $vars[] = 'ebook_cat';
  $vars[] = 'ebooks_id';
  return $vars;
 }

 //register activation function
 register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ebook_plugin_activate');
 //register deactivation function
 register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'ebook_plugin_deactivate');
 //add rewrite rules in case another plugin flushes rules
 add_action('init', 'ebook_plugin_rules');
 //add plugin query vars (product_id) to wordpress
 add_filter('query_vars', 'ebook_plugin_query_vars');
```